# How do I create a global variable among multiple files?

Tags: c++

I am trying to add a simple boolean variable that I can change from multiple files. At least be able to change from `marlin_main.cpp`. I read I have to declare on a header file then define on one other file that includes the header and I should be able to use it.

I added

```
static bool endstopDisabled;
```

to the header file then declared it in its .cpp file

```
bool endstopDisabled;
```

It compiles fine but when I try to use it like this

```
endstopDisabled = false;
```

below in the same .cpp file it doesn't compile. It gives me the error "Error compiling for board Sanguino.". Anyone know what I am doing wrong? All I need is a boolean variable accessible to 2 files: `Marlin_main.cpp` and `endstops.cpp`. I am declaring variable in `endstops.h`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I had to declare the variable in endstops.cpp with `bool Endstops::endstopDisabled;` instead.